# how to pass data from a model to the url in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a customized user model like this:

```
class Utilisateur(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

And I have my view declared this way:

```
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

So I want my URL to appear with username in it, something like this : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/username1/`

How can I pass the username to the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the URL dispatcher documentation of django. It has covered most of the usage patterns.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/

In your `urls.py` you have to defined the variable part of the URL which should contain the username. Something like:

```py
from django.urls import path

from .views import profile

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<str:username>/', profile, name='user_profile'),
]
```

In your `views.py` you have to adjust your view to receive the URL argument:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def profile(request, username):
    # do whatever you want,
    # maybe getting the user for the provided username and pass it to the template
    user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), username=username)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user': user})
```

The templates may contain the URL to any profile, which is generated with the `{% url 'name' arguments %}` template tag.

```html
This is the profile of
<a href="{% url 'user_profile' username=user.username %}">
  {{ user.username }}
</a>
```

Comment: i can't use the "get_user_model()" or "get_object_or_404()" method cause its a custom authentication and user model made by me not the default user library that comes with django

Comment: Well, you can just change to code to fit your needs. The general idea should fit anyway.

Comment: You should set AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings file (if you have customized it as you said). If you set it before then you can use get_user_model or other helper methods with it.

Answer (score 0):

In your URL conf:

```py
path('profile/<str:username>/', profile)
```

Don't forget to add the username wherever the link is displayed.